# Stop Gridview Value to change when I click on Edit buitton

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I need help with this Gridview issue. I build a dropdown search on the Gridview base on the ID as shown by the image below

[image]

The problem I have is when I click the Edit button to update the Gridview the value of the Gridview change and go back to the first value in the table as shown by the image below

[image]

C# Code GridViewMYD88_RowUpdating

```
  protected void GridViewMYD88_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
        GridViewRow row = GridViewMYD88.Rows[e.RowIndex];

        Label TestID = (Label)GridViewMYD88.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("lblId");
        Label SampleBranchID = (Label)GridViewMYD88.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("lblSampleBranchID");


        string TechniqueforMYD88  = (row.FindControl("txtTechniqueforMYD88") as TextBox).Text;
        string MYD88ExonsAnalyzed = (row.FindControl("txtMYD88ExonsAnalyzed") as TextBox).Text;
        string SequenceofEntireMYD88 = (row.FindControl("txtSequenceofEntireMYD88") as TextBox).Text;
        string MYD88MutationStatus = (row.FindControl("txtMYD88MutationStatus") as TextBox).Text;
        string NumberofMYD88Mutations = (row.FindControl("txtNumberofMYD88Mutations") as TextBox).Text;
        string MYD88pL265PMutation = (row.FindControl("txtMYD88pL265PMutation") as TextBox).Text;
        string OtherMYD88MutationDescription = (row.FindControl("txtOtherMYD88MutationDescription") as TextBox).Text;
        string MYD88VAFPercentage = (row.FindControl("txtMYD88VAFPercentage") as TextBox).Text;
        string MYD88RefAllelesReads = (row.FindControl("txtMYD88RefAllelesReads") as TextBox).Text;
        string MYD88VariantAllelesReads = (row.FindControl("txtMYD88VariantAllelesReads") as TextBox).Text;
        string MYD88OverallReadDepth = (row.FindControl("txtMYD88OverallReadDepth") as TextBox).Text;

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Molecular"].ConnectionString))
        {
            con.Open();

            using (SqlCommand sc = new SqlCommand(@"UPDATE MutationResults

                            SET TechniqueforMYD88=@TechniqueforMYD88, MYD88ExonsAnalyzed=@MYD88ExonsAnalyzed, SequenceofEntireMYD88=@SequenceofEntireMYD88,

                            MYD88MutationStatus=@MYD88MutationStatus, NumberofMYD88Mutations=@NumberofMYD88Mutations, MYD88pL265PMutation=@MYD88pL265PMutation,

                            OtherMYD88MutationDescription=@OtherMYD88MutationDescription, MYD88VAFPercentage=@MYD88VAFPercentage, MYD88RefAllelesReads=@MYD88RefAllelesReads,

                            MYD88VariantAllelesReads=@MYD88VariantAllelesReads, MYD88OverallReadDepth=@MYD88OverallReadDepth

                             WHERE 

                            ID=@TestID and SampleBranchID=@SampleBranchID", con))
            {
                sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TestID", TestID.Text);
                sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SampleBranchID", SampleBranchID.Text);
                sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TechniqueforMYD88", TechniqueforMYD88);
                sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MYD88ExonsAnalyzed", MYD88ExonsAnalyzed);
                sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SequenceofEntireMYD88", SequenceofEntireMYD88);
                sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MYD88MutationStatus", MYD88MutationStatus);
                sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NumberofMYD88Mutations", NumberofMYD88Mutations);
                sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MYD88pL265PMutation", MYD88pL265PMutation);
                sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OtherMYD88MutationDescription", OtherMYD88MutationDescription);
                sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MYD88VAFPercentage", MYD88VAFPercentage);
                sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MYD88RefAllelesReads", MYD88RefAllelesReads);
                sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MYD88VariantAllelesReads", MYD88VariantAllelesReads);
                sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MYD88OverallReadDepth", MYD88OverallReadDepth);

                sc.ExecuteScalar();

            }
            con.Close();
        }


        GridViewMYD88.EditIndex = -1;
        this.BindGridMutationResults();
    }
```

Any help how to solve this issue. Thanks

Comment: What happens inside the `RowUpdating` method?

Comment: @vDWWD RowUpdating update the table with the new value enter. That work find. The problem is when I click edit the value of the gridview change to the first value in the table therefore the value in the gridview doesn’t matched the ID search in the Dropdown

Comment: Then show some code what happens in the SelectedIndexChanged. Without code we cant help.

Comment: @VDWWD Just added C# Code. Thanks

Comment: Debug the values of `@TestID` and `@SampleBranchID` to check if they are what you thinkg they are. And make sure that the binding of the GridView is wrappen inside an `!IsPostBack` check.

Comment: @VDWWDif you look the two images you will see the id is different . That is my problem. When I select the ID in the dropdown box in image 1  the Gridview will display the right value but when I click on edit the value in the gridview in image 2  get update to the first data in the table. Debug is sending the TestID and SampleID in the gridview